# Is there a better way I can write a repetitive CASE statement group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Here is an example:

```sql
CASE WHEN [b].Indicator IN ('J','JJ') AND [b].Name NOT IN ('') THEN [c].Address1 ELSE [b].Address1 END AS ShipToAddress1,
CASE WHEN [b].Indicator IN ('J','JJ') AND [b].Name NOT IN ('') THEN [c].Address2 ELSE [b].Address2 END AS ShipToAddress2,
CASE WHEN [b].Indicator IN ('J','JJ') AND [b].Name NOT IN ('') THEN [c].Address3 ELSE [b].Address3 END AS ShipToAddress3,
CASE WHEN [b].Indicator IN ('J','JJ') AND [b].Name NOT IN ('') THEN [c].Address4 ELSE [b].Address4 END AS ShipToAddress4
```

There is a switch-up in the database where I was asked to swap columns for reporting if an indicator exists. There are more than 4 of these and I'd like to believe there is a way to make this more concise.

Comment: You might be able toalter your `JOIN` logic and then you could just use `ISNUL`L`/`COALESCE` in the `SELECT`; but there isn't enough information above to determine that.

Comment: What are the possible values of *indicator*? you might be able to use `like`, not possible to say without a lot more detail.